# Number of votes on duplicate suggestions while asking a question are placed wrongly

Tags: bug, asking-questions, duplicate-suggestions

While asking a question we get some suggestions for duplicates with the number of votes. But it is not place correctly. Have a look at this:

> [image]

Those questions are listed as follow:

- [Why are these reversed downvotes recorded as undownvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127637/187824)
- [Allow votes to lock a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51033/187824)
- [does serial undownvote script kick in after duplicate accounts merge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132589/187824)
- [How did this curious undownvote pattern come about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156507/187824)
- [Why are upvotes and downvotes locked after 5 minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176148/187824)

OS: Windows XP, Chrome 28.0.1500.95 m, Firefox 22.0